# csgo_linux64 is not responding on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, games, steam, crash

Everytime I launch csgo, the game keep crashing. sometimes I can get into the game but its like 1:30 attempt.
I already have tried re-installing Ubuntu, re-installing steam & CSGO, run steam from terminal, still not solving the problem.

[Everytime I tried to launch always receiving this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGO89.png)

And when I run from Terminal and crash, I found out this :

```
>>> Adding process 6036 for game ID 730
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Game removed: AppID 730 "", ProcID 5973 
JS method call WebChat.GetOverlayChatBrowserInfo with 1 arguments
assert_20180819064942_1.dmp[6037]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20180819064942_1.dmp[6037]: response: Discarded=1
assert_20180819064942_1.dmp[6037]: file ''/tm/dump/assert_20180819064942_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''Discarded=1''
pid 6037 != 6036, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add -nojoy to launch options. Can you make sure that you don't have joystick connected to your PC? From my experience and people who had the same issue it was due to joystick being connected to PC. You can override that with -nojoy option in launch options or just disconnect it.

Cheers!